# What would happen if I abruptly close my script while it's still doing file I/O operations?

Tags: python, file-io

here's my question: I'm writing a script to check if my website running all right, the basic idea is to get the server response time and similar stuff every 5 minutes or so, and the script will log the info each time after checking the server status. I know it's no good to close the script while it's in the middle of checking/writing logs, but I'm curious if there are lots of server to check and also you have to do the file I/O pretty frequently, what would happen if you abruptly close the script?

OK, here's an example:

```
while True:
    DemoFile = open("DemoFile.txt", "a")
    DemoFile.write("This is a test!")
    DemoFile.close()

    time.sleep(30)
```

If I accidentally close the script while this line `DemoFile.write("This is a test!")` is running, what would I get in the DemoFile.txt? Do I get "This i"(an incomplete line) or the complete line or the line not even added?

Hopefully somebody knows the answer.

Comment: Depends on the operating system.

Comment: @İsmail 'cartman' Dönmez: What would happen in win XP?

Comment: When you tried it, what happened?

Comment: @S.Lott: Well, I don't really know if the moment I close the script is just the time it's running that exact line. I'm curious and don't know how to test, so here comes this question...

Comment: @Shane: Do this: break your writes into four steps.  Write, print to sys.stdout, sleep and then write some more.  You can then use Ctrl-C while it's sleeping to break before the close.  Try it.

Comment: @S.Lott: Now I know there would never be an incomplete line such as "This i" be written into the file whenever you force the script to quit. But this actually made me come up with a new question: what would happen if there's a power failure while the os is in the middle of doing file I/O operations? Would incomplete line "This i" appear? If the os is trying to append stuff to a file, would this also affect previous file content? Data lost?

Comment: @Shane: Correct.  Power failure is data lost.  What else can possibly happen?  Magical preservation of data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [python io documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/io.html), buffering is handled according to the buffering parameter to the open function.

The default behavior in this case would be either the device's block size or io.DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE if the block size can't be determined. This is probably something like 4096 bytes.

<strike>In short, that example will write nothing. If you were writing something long enough that the buffer was written once or twice, you'd have multiples of the buffer size written. And you can always manually flush the buffer with flush().</strike>

(If you specify buffering as 0 and the file mode as binary, you'd get "This i". That's the only way, though)

As @sven pointed out, python isn't doing the buffering. When the program is terminated, all open file descriptors are closed and flushed by the operating system.

Comment: Wouldn't the file be closed and the buffer flushed on termination of the script?  And wouldn't the operating system do buffering even if the Python `io` module does not?

Comment: well, I just tested it and it looks like it does. so I stand corrected. @sven: according to the docs, it appears that only the os mechanism is used; the open parameters just change what arguments are used with the underlying syscall