# What would happen if there's a power failure while the OS is in the middle of doing file I/O operations?

Tags: python, file-io, operating-system

OK, this question is actually a follow-up question from my previous one: [What would happen if I abruptly close my script while it's still doing file I/O operations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4615905/what-would-happen-if-i-abruptly-close-my-script-while-its-still-doing-file-i-o-o)

So it's not possible to see an incomplete line written into a file whenever you force your script/program to quit, as the OS will do their job. But what if there's a power failure, and the OS is just in the middle of appending one line such as "This is a test"(or even bigger strings) into a file, do I get an incomplete line appended or nothing appended or even worse, previous content lost? I'm really curious to know, and this kind of situation would definitely happen on the server side. Anybody can help me out?

Comment: Why don't you try it and let us know?

Comment: If you're really worried about this, write to a database that supports transactions.

Comment: @erjiang: What do you think I'm here for?

Comment: @chrisaycock: Thanks. But my point is to know how the OS works, hopefully somebody can fill me in.

Comment: You can reduce the risk of this happening by making use a of quality [UPS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uninterruptible_power_supply).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rule 1.  There's no magic.  No guarantee.  No assurance.  Power failure means the circuitry passes through states that are outside their design tolerances.  Anything could happen.  No guarantees.

> what if there's a power failure, and the OS is just in the middle of appending ... into a file, do I get an incomplete line appended

Possibly.  There's no magic.  The I/O could include two physical blocks.  One written, one unwritten.

> or nothing appended

Possibly.  There's no magic.  The I/O buffer may not have been synced to the device.

> or even worse, previous content lost?

Possibly.  There's no magic.  A block write to the device could -- during a power failure -- fatally corrupt bits on the device.

> I'm really curious to know, and this kind of situation would definitely happen on the server side.

"Definitely"?  Nothing's definite during an uncontrollable event like a power failure.  Anything could happen.

There's a really small possibility that the random scrambled bits could be the text of Lincoln's Gettysburg Address and that's what appears on the device.

Comment: He means, power failures can definitely happen on the server side. That is, in fact, a definite possibility.

Comment: @S.Lott: Does this mean if you are writing a txt document, already finished 10,000 lines, and there's a power failure while you hit the save button, and you restart the os just might find all your written gone or file corrupted? OK, I think I know the importance of data backups.

Comment: Read my answer, you can find both the txt document and some system files are gone after the restart. So, yeah, do backup :)

Comment: @Shane: A power failure means that the machine will not work correctly.  Anything could happen.  Manufacturers and software developers try to minimize the anything.  But there's no magic.  It's electronics passing through undefined (and undefinable) states of energy.  Anything can happen.  There are no magical guarantees.

Comment: @S.Lott: Thanks for being patient to my questions. : )

Answer (score 1):

It is dependent on FileSystem (and its options), hardware (caches/buffers, media, etc.), application behavior and lots of other tidbits.

You can [lose data](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/317781?comments=all), even data you had safely written before. You can corrupt whole partitions. You can get garbage on files. You can get a line half-written, half-laden with garbage or whatever. Given the right combination of factors, you can pretty much get any result you imagine, files with mixed contents, old bits of deleted files resurfacing, dogs and cats living together... mass hysteria!

With a proper (journaled? versioned?) FS and sane hardware, you do lower the amount of chaos possible.